# How to create a google contact from command line?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, google

I can use [goobook](https://pypi.org/project/goobook/) to create a google contact with NAME and EMAIL but I need to add a PHONE.

Comment: `goobook add` can either read an e-mail or take 2 parameters from the command line. I guess that currently you're adding new contacts using the latter, right?

Comment: Anyway, it wasn't very hard to modify `goobok` source code so that it accepts phone number parameter with `add` option like that: `./goobook add my-test-with-phone goobook-with-phone@test.com 666666666`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have patched `goobook` to accept a phone number when adding new
contacts.  Clone my forked repository:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/ardrabczyk/goobook && cd goobook
```

Now you can follow the instructions in `README.rst`. In this case, as
you're now installing `goobook` from source just do this:

```
sudo python3 ./setup.py install
```

Personally, I don't like installing packages globally and using `sudo`
if there's no such need so consider doing this instead:

```
python3 setup.py install --user
```

You won't need to enter `root's` password and `goobook` will be installed
to `~/.local/bin`. Check the new help for `add` command:

```
$ ~/.local/bin/goobook  add -h
usage: goobook add [-h] [NAME] [EMAIL] [PHONE]

Create new contact, if name and email is not given the sender of a mail read
from stdin will be used.

positional arguments:
  NAME        Name to use.
  EMAIL       E-mail to use.
  PHONE       Phone number to use.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Add a new test entry with a phone number:

```
~/.local/bin/goobook  add fork-goobook fork@fork.com 789456123
```

Make sure it was created correctly:

```
$ ~/.local/bin/goobook  query 789456123

fork@fork.com   fork@fork.com
```

Keep in mind that the change I've introduced has not been formally accepted
by `goobook` developers and that you're now using a
[fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)).

Comment: Notice this bug: https://gitlab.com/goobook/goobook/issues/82. It's
also present in my fork as it has not yet been solved by upstream
developers.

Comment: Thank you so much @Arkadiusz ! I really appreciate your work. I hope the bug can be solved soon, then this app will be perfect for use.

Comment: goobook version 1.9 does NOT have that bug. Would I be asking too much for you to fork that version? Again thank you so much for looking at this!

Comment: I think it would be much better to fix this bug against the current version. It now works for me, I think so at least. Do `git fetch` and switch to `issue-82` branch

Comment: I feel I can't thank you enough! I'm very grateful. Thank you!